# can't connect to database in website

Tags: php, mysql

I use this following codes to make new users in website. it's like sign up page. it's working perfectly in localhost and data will insert to the database and the table but now in the server it won't work.

```
  $code = rand(11111,99999);
    $link1 = mysql_connect("http://www.mysite.com","username","password");
     mysql_select_db("username");
     mysql_query("SET character_set_results= 'utf8' , character_set_client = 'utf8' , character_set_connection = 'utf8',
     character_set_database ='utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8' ");
     mysql_query("INSERT into user(name,family,email,gender,username,pass)
     values('$_POST[name]','$_POST[family]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[username]','$code')");
     mysql_close($link1);
     //connection user pass
     $link2 = mysql_connect("http://www.mysite.com","username","password");
     mysql_select_db("username");
     mysql_query("INSERT into joinuser(username,pass,permission)values('$_POST[username]','$code','user')" );
     mysql_close($link2);
```

It inserts the values in localhost but it won't work in the server.

It's php with mysql database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try using the ip address of ur database server in place of www.mysite.com

Comment: You are using [an obsolete database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also exposing yourself to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/) that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). Your code is *extremely* vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: If the page is on the server, wouldn't be "localhost" instead of "www.mysite.com" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"http://www.mysite.com"` is wrong. You cannot connect to MySQL using HTTP.

In most cases, you will only ever need to use `localhost` and allow the library to connect via a local socket rather than TCP/IP.

If you are connected to a database server running on a different machine to the HTTP server, then you would use the hostname (and optionally the port). You wouldn't specify a URL scheme of any kind.

Comment: should I still use localhost to connecting to the server?

Comment: If the database server and the HTTP server are running on the same machine, yes.

Comment: You should use (and create if needed) a database user with the minimum permissions needed for the website to function.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this will be the solution of the problem.

```
//mysql_connect("http://www.mysite.com","username","password");
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
```

Notice the `localhost` in stead of `http://www.mysite.com`.